# yield tuples where all the elements are ints

Tags: python, list

I'm writing a function that receive an iterable of tuples, then I have to yield tuples that all elements are ints. Which the conditions:

For each element in the tuple:

- if it is an int, leave it unchanged
- if it is a str, convert it to an int(if possible, see example below)
- otherwise, return None

  ```
  For example: 

  list(func([(1, "48")])) = [(1, 48)]
  list(func([(1, "0xf")])) = [(1, 15)]
  list(func([(1, "junk")]))  = None
  list(func([([3], 4)])) = None
  ```

Here's my code so far, look nasty and doesnt work

```
 def func(iterable):
     for x in iterable:
        for i in x:
           if not ((isinstance(i, str) and i.isdigit()) or (isinstance(i, str) and isinstance(int(i, 16), int)) or isinstance(i, int)):
              yield None
      yield [i if isinstance(i, int) else int(i) if i.isdigit() else int(i, 16) for i in x for x in iterable]
```

Do you have a better solution for this>? i'm new to python, any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Python believes in "if it's a duck, it's a duck". You'd be better off calling int() on each element, and catching exceptions rather than using isinstance.

Comment: I can't help but notice a distinct absence of `yield` in this attempt. Are you aware of what `yield` is?

Comment: Are your strings guaranteed only to be 1 char?  Your dec/hex switching logic will fall over if not.

Comment: Also, do you really mean `return None`, as in "forget all of the other elements that _were_ good, if a single one is bad don't return anything?"

Comment: Also, don't chain together `if…else` expressions. It makes your code hard to read and hard to debug. Even moreso for people trying to read them in an 80-column window like a StackOverflow question or a typical terminal.

Comment: Also, this is weird logic. If I want to give you a hexadecimal number that happens not to have any `A`-`F` digits, you're going to silently treat it as a very different number.

Comment: @SilasRay: No, try `'123'.isdigit()` and `'1a3'.isdigit()`. it does exactly what he appears to want (as weird a thing as it is to want).

Comment: sorry guys! above are the example, how do we deal with the case "0xf" in example 2

Comment: @abarnet, I was more referencing the ambiguous case of `int('12', 10)` vs `int('12', 16)`.  If you use the fact that `isdigit` returns `False` to check for base of a stringified number, you are implicitly assuming that every multidigit number represeneted in string format that is intended to be hex has a digit above 9 in it (or has an `0x` prefix, I suppose...).

Comment: "*`list(func([([3], 4)])) = None`*" -- I'm pretty sure the list constructor is never going to return None under any circumstance.

Comment: it yield only int element and str elements that can be converted to int :|

Comment: I still don't think you get the point of `yield`. This will yield a whole bunch of `None` values if there are any bad values, then raise an exception; otherwise, it will yield exactly one value. Your desired output looks nothing like that.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit of a strange thing, but it looks like you want to handle any Python integer literal format as if it were an `int`. The best way to do that is probably to call `ast.literal_eval` to parse it, then see if it parsed to an `int`. Like this:

```
def intify(x):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return x
    parsed = ast.literal_eval(x)
    if isinstance(parsed, int):
        return parsed
    raise ValueError('{} is not an int literal'.format(x))
```

<sub>Note that you might want to instead test `isinstance(x, numbers.Integral)` and if so return `int(x)`, or even just return `int(x)` whenever it succeeds, or something different, depending on what you want to do with things that are `int`-like and `int`-convertible but not actually `int`, for some appropriate definition of `int`-like.</sub>

Now, you just do this:

```
try:
    return tuple(intify(x) for x in iterable)
except ValueError:
    return None
```

And if you want to do that for a whole iterable of iterables, you need a nested loop, like this:

```
try:
    return [tuple(intify(x) for x in subiterable) for subiterable in iterable]
except ValueError:
    return None
```

---

If you want to do this lazily, yielding the elements without ever building a list, there's no way to "bail out early" and return `None`—once you've already yielded some values, you can't unyield them. So, what you want isn't directly possible. But if you could explain why you want it, something similarly useful might be actually doable. For example:

```
yield from (tuple(intify(x) for x in subiterable) for subiterable in iterable)
```

Or, if you don't have Python 3.3:

```
for subiterable in iterable:
    yield tuple(intify(x) for x in subiterable)
```

This will raise an exception on the first bad value. So, if you're just using the iterator to pass to a call to `list`, the partially-built list will be abandoned to handle the exception.

Then again, if the only thing you're doing with this function is building a list, there's really no reason to use a generator in the first place; just return a list.

Comment: I like this answer but with a quick warning that you really are getting python's view of ints. For instance, '010' is 8. So make sure that your idea of leading zeros fits python's.

Comment: @tdelaney: I _think_ that's what the OP wanted. Or, if not Python's view of ints, then maybe JavaScript's or C's or the `chmod` command's or something else. But of course I could be wrong. (Also, note that `010` is not `8` in Python 3, it's a `SyntaxError`, precisely because they decided that avoiding confusion was more important than parsing C literals.)

Comment: So 70's era string conventions are finally dropping away in python 3. I think maybe its time to toss that PDP-11 reference manual.

Comment: @tdelaney: But without the PDP-11 reference manual, how would you remember that bytes are 8 bits rather than 9 nowadays? :)

Comment: can someone explain to me why `010` was EVER 8? Shouldn't it be 2?

Comment: @AdamSmith: Mainly it's because octal (3 bits per digit) was a lot more useful than hexadecimal (4 bits per digit) on machines with 9-, 12-, 18-, 24-, or 36-bit bytes or words, like the 18-bit PDP-7 that Thompson and Ritchie invented Unix on. (Notice that basic rwxrwxrwx file permissions are still 9 bits of data; although of course they found ways to use the other bits later, you still typically write `chmod 755 spam` to set rwxr-xr-x…)

Comment: @abarnert OH of course it's octal. I thought the preceding `0` indicated binary.

Comment: @AdamSmith: Binary literals, in 1972? That's 19 characters per word instead of 7! Do you have stock in the magnetic tape company?

Answer (score 0):

My (untested) take:

```
def to_int(item):
    try:
        return int(item)
    except ValueError:
        return None

def func(iterable):
    for input_tuple in iterable:
        yield tuple(to_int(item) for item in input_tuple)
```

I assume "for each element in the tuple" if it is not possible to convert to int you will return None for that element, not for the whole tuple.

[update]

Now that you updated the question, there is no point using `yield` if you want `func([(1, "junk")])` to return `None` when any unconvertible item occurs anywhere on the input; the whole point of `yield` is to start returning values as soon as you compute them. For the desired output you have to hold the result until you process the whole list. Perhaps you misread your assignment?

Comment: This misses all the weird hex logic

Comment: I will leave the required "to_int" function as an exercise to the OP, I was just showing how I would organize the code, not doing his homework. :-)